# Add a "," in a string where in it there is this: "}{"

Tags: android, json, string

I'm working in a Android app and i need to put a "," between "}{" in my jsonstring before i can work with  String#split(). For example i have this:

```
{"field1":"A","field2":"abcbab","field3":5}
    {"field1":"B","field2":"fakfef","field3":25} 
    {"field1":"A","field2":"faefe","field3":12}
```

how can i do that?

Comment: can't you tell whoever is sending you this string to get it right?

Comment: i'm sending this string from php. It's from three different json_encode and i don't know why there isn't the ","

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
String newJsonStr = yourJsonStr.replaceAll("\\}\\s*\\{", "},{");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String text = "To be or,not,to be, that is the question.";
      String k=",{}";
        String newText = text.replaceAll(",", k);    // Modify the string text

        System.out.println(newText);
```

> try this it will solve your problem

Comment: Sorry but what is 'd' character? I don't have spaces between } and {

Comment: u can't replace one character with 2 characters normally@tittarella

Comment: i don't want to replace, i want to add a character in each }{ of the string, it's inpossible?

Comment: try this one it will solve here take text=yourstring and try@tittarella